# In a finite state machine, can a state generate an event?

Tags: state-machine

In a finite state machine, can a state S1 generate an event, so this event will trigger a transition from this state S1 to another state S2 ?

Comment: Yes, States can emit events which trigger a transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this way of visualizing FSM in software

```
         Start

           |

       =Initial=   <---------------------------------
     --------------                                 |
    | Transition 1 | --------->     =State 2=       |
     --------------              ---------------    |
    | Transition 2 | -------    |  Transition   | --|
     --------------        |     ---------------    |
                           |                        |
                           |                        |
                           |                        |
                           --->     =State 3=       |
                                 ---------------    |
                                |  Transition   | ---
                                 ---------------
```

In this scenario the `Initial` state will execute upon some path that can then transition into `Transition 1` or `Transition 2`. `Transition 1` starts `State 2` while `Transition 2` starts `State 3`. The `Initial` state can emit an event saying it will take the transition `Transition 1` and your framework then can execute that transition.

You'll also notice that I do not have an end in this FSM. You need an end or a closed looped.

Answer (score 4):

From a computational-theory standpoint, the only function of a "pure" finite state machine is to convert a string of input to a one-of-N choice (in most illustrations it's a one-of-two (accept vs reject) choice, but larger finite values of N work are conceptually the same).  Two pure finite state machines are equivalent if for any sequence of input characters they will return the same one-of-N result.  A step up from a pure finite state machine is a finite state transducer, in which every edge can cause an arbitrary number of characters to be sent to an output stream *which has no effect on any future state transitions*.  Two such machines are equivalent if for any sequence of input characters they will generate the same sequence of output characters and will return the same one-of-N result.

Given two pure finite state machines or two pure finite state transducers, it is possible to determine within a reasonable bounded time whether they are equivalent (if two transducers, the smaller of which has N states, will produce the same sequence of outputs for any input sequence of up to 2N characters, they will produce the same output sequence for any input sequence for any input sequence of any length).  The same approach may be used if state machines are allowed to generate "events" which can in turn affect their inputs, but two machines are only considered equivalent if they generate the exact same sequence of events, and if all combinations of inputs are presumed to be possible regardless of the events generated.  On the other hand, if there is some type of event that can affect the state machine's input in some way but is not of interest to the user of the machine, or if certain sequences of events would mean that certain sequences of inputs could not occur, it may be very difficult (or even essentially impossible) to determine whether two machines which may differ in ways the user doesn't care about, are equivalent in ways the user does care about.

State machines which trigger events that influence their input are often useful in the real world, but such machines cannot be analyzed using the methods that are applicable to simpler machines.  Effectively, the linkage between the output and the input needs to be regarded as part of the state machine; many such linkage mechanisms have a number of states which totally dwarfs the number of potential states in the DFA to which they are attached (if it's bounded at all).

Answer (score 2):

There are many different definitions and models for state machines.

In hardware design they talk about Mealy machines and Moore machines, which differ in which of the various wired lead back to the inputs...

In software, FSM's are less-strictly defined. The whole computer is in some sense one big state machine. A lot of code implements a state machine as a simple switch statement, and may or may not also post events to itself.

A popular definition for software state machines is UML State Machines (which is nice because it comes with a preferred picture format, too.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine

UML State machines can have an entry() action and exit() action for each state. Depending on the implementation, you could have those actions post additional events.

So, "Can an FSM trigger a transition"? Depends on the definition or implementation. Generally, Sure!

Comment: So, in a UML State Machine, the internal transition of a state can trigger an event ?

Comment: any of the "Actions" can post an event...
Or use internal transitions.